# SQL Return distinct rows based on two columns by rounding column to nearest value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

Following is the Table:

```
ID  C1  C2  C3  Date    C5  C6  Name
1   ### ### ### 9.53    ### ### ron
1   ### ### ### 9.57    ### ### ron
1   ### ### ### 9.87    ### ### ron
1   ### ### ### 10.2    ### ### jess
1   ### ### ### 10.2    ### ### jess
1   ### ### ### 11.3    ### ### mike
1   ### ### ### 11.3    ### ### mike
2   ### ### ### 16.58   ### ### ron
2   ### ### ### 16.33   ### ### ron
2   ### ### ### 16.45   ### ### ron
2   ### ### ### 22.43   ### ### jess
2   ### ### ### 22.88   ### ### jess
2   ### ### ### 19.2    ### ### mike
2   ### ### ### 19.51   ### ### mike
```

Following is what i am expecting:

Gettting distinct rows based on ID and Name, grouping by Date to nearest round number.

```
ID  C1  C2  C3  Date    C5  C6  Name
1   ### ### ### 9      ###  ### ron
1   ### ### ### 10     ###  ### jess
1   ### ### ### 11     ###  ### mike
2   ### ### ### 16     ###  ### ron
2   ### ### ### 22     ###  ### jess
2   ### ### ### 19     ###  ### mike
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I don't understand your rounding logic.  Can you explain it?

Comment: get distinct rows based on ID, Name and Date (rounded to the nearest integer)

Comment: But why are the values in that column not integers if they are rounded to nearest integer?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited and reposted it

Comment: can we just use ceil, not exactly rounding

Comment: What happens if, for example, an `ID` and `Name` has 12.5, 13.5, and 14.5 as values?  Which value gets chosen?

Comment: I would say, use either FLOOR() or CEIL() functions of SQL on Date column and use the computed value in DISTINCT() function.
These functions are available based on your database provider.

Comment: All three must be shown as separate rows...

Comment: select  distinct [ID], [C1], [C2], [C3], cast(date as int), [C5], [C6], [Name]  from #Table1

Comment: @Chanukya: you are considering only distinct ids. I also want it to be distinct by name. Because sometimes id and rounding the date value would be the same but will have different names

Comment: @blackfury just try in sql server what i have wrote and check output

Comment: What is the logic for determining _which_ of the records gets retained?  I.e. how do we know which other columns' values get retained?

Comment: @Chakunya: I still get all rows returned when the multiple names have same id

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: The logic is all records having unique id and unique name must be retained with a group by on date

Comment: Are you actually expecting C1, C2, C3, C5, and C6 in your output? If so, if two rows have different C1s, but the same id, name, and truncated date, how will the C1s be combined?

Comment: @EdmCoff: C1, C2 all maybe same or different. Only columns that need to be considered are the id, name and truncated date

Comment: So you don't want to select them? Then use @chanukya's suggestion of "select distinct ID, cast(Date as int), Name from mytable" (the distinct applies to all columns in the select list, not just the ID).

Comment: Yeah... Chakunya Answer worked. @Chanukya, do u mind posting your answer. I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @blackfury i posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([ID] int, [C1] varchar(3), [C2] varchar(3), [C3] varchar(3), [Date] numeric(10,4), [C5] varchar(3), [C6] varchar(3), [Name] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([ID], [C1], [C2], [C3], [Date], [C5], [C6], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, '###', '###', '###', 9.53, '###', '###', 'ron'),
    (1, '###', '###', '###', 9.57, '###', '###', 'ron'),
    (1, '###', '###', '###', 9.87, '###', '###', 'ron'),
    (1, '###', '###', '###', 10.2, '###', '###', 'jess'),
    (1, '###', '###', '###', 10.2, '###', '###', 'jess'),
    (1, '###', '###', '###', 11.3, '###', '###', 'mike'),
    (1, '###', '###', '###', 11.3, '###', '###', 'mike'),
    (2, '###', '###', '###', 16.58, '###', '###', 'ron'),
    (2, '###', '###', '###', 16.33, '###', '###', 'ron'),
    (2, '###', '###', '###', 16.45, '###', '###', 'ron'),
    (2, '###', '###', '###', 22.43, '###', '###', 'jess'),
    (2, '###', '###', '###', 22.88, '###', '###', 'jess'),
    (2, '###', '###', '###', 19.2, '###', '###', 'mike'),
    (2, '###', '###', '###', 19.51, '###', '###', 'mike')
;
select  distinct [ID], [C1], [C2], [C3], cast(date as int), [C5], [C6], [Name]  from #Table1
```

Answer (score 3):

is this helpful

```
    create table #tmp (Date float, Name varchar(10))

    insert into #tmp values(9.53,'ron')
    insert into #tmp values(9.57,'ron')
    insert into #tmp values(9.87,'ron')

    insert into #tmp values(10.2,'jess')
    insert into #tmp values(10.2,'jess')

    insert into #tmp values(11.3,'mike')
    insert into #tmp values(11.3,'mike')

    insert into #tmp values(16.58,'ron')
    insert into #tmp values(16.33,'ron')
    insert into #tmp values(16.45,'ron')

    insert into #tmp values(22.43,'jess')
    insert into #tmp values(22.88,'jess')

    insert into #tmp values(19.2,'mike')
    insert into #tmp values(19.51,'mike')



    SELECT DISTINCT floor(Date) AS Date,Name from #tmp

    drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Rounded_Date, Name
FROM
(SELECT ID, FLOOR(Date) Rounded_Date, Name FROM Your_Table);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirement, I think this might give you the expected result

```
;with cte
as
(
select
  SeqNo = row_number() over(partition by
                            ID,
  C1,
  C2,
  C3,
  cast(Date as int),
  C5,
  C6,
  Name order by id),
  ID,
  C1,
  C2,
  C3,
  Date,
  C5,
  C6,
  Name
  from t1

)
select
ID,
  C1,
  C2,
  C3,
  Date,
  C5,
  C6,
  Name
from cte where seqNo = 1
```

Check the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7284/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
  select distinct id, round(date,0) as date,name from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
select ID, C1, C2, C3, floor(Date) as RDate, C5, C6, Name
from your_table_name
group by ID, Name, RDate
```